# Does anyone have a solution for this js error ??(Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' )

Tags: javascript

I am new at javascript. I created one project, but when i am run this code at time get error related to (.) doat. I think there is no syntax error in code but i am still getting this error message. does anyone have a solution for this f**ing error??

Error Message :-
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Why i am getting fucking error</title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <iframe id=target></iframe>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var target = document.getElementById('target')
    
    target.addEventListener('load', {} >= {
      
      target.contentWindow.postMessage({"msg": "Hello", "payload": "hello2"}, 'http://example.com/')
    
    })
    
    target.src = "http://example.com/"
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Alot of typos in your scripts. May be read here how to use [addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: Also read here on [MDN how to use the fat arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your anonymous function lambda, it should be `()=>`, also change `http` to `https`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Why i am getting fucking error</title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <iframe id=target></iframe>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var target = document.getElementById('target')
    
    target.addEventListener('load', () => {
      
      target.contentWindow.postMessage({"msg": "Hello", "payload": "hello2"}, 'https://example.com/')
    
    })
    
    target.src = "https://example.com/"
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro....... It working 101%

Comment: Again thank you for amazing solution

Answer (score 0):

Dont curse everyone do mistakes
You are not writing the code in right syntax here is the right syntax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Why i am getting fucking error</title>

</head>
<body>

<iframe id=target></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
var target = document.getElementById('target')

target.addEventListener('load', () => {//this is the correct es6 syntax in javascript
  
  target.contentWindow.postMessage({"msg": "Hello", "payload": "hello2"}, 'http://example.com/')

})

target.src = "http://example.com/"
</script>

</body>
</html>
```